# Getting URL of archive (category) page

Tags: categories, functions

I'm trying to retrieve the current URL of the page, which works everywhere except for archive pages, for example, a category page. On a category page, it shows as the most recent post in that category.

```
$this_id = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object_id();
$this_url = get_permalink($this_id);
echo $this_url; // Should show like: http://domain.com/blog/category
```

How do I retrieve the actual archive page URL?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but here is a solution from [Konstantin Kovshenin](http://kovshenin.com/2012/current-url-in-wordpress/)

```
global $wp;
$current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
```

You can then just simply `echo $current_url`

Answer (score 0):

Category URLs can be retrieved using function `get_category_link`. So instead of using `get_permalink` , if you use `get_category_link` and pass the category id to it, it would return the link of the category. You can read more about `get_category_link` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link).

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the first answer, from Pieter Goosen:

Using same code but without the current category/tag/taxonomy being repeated with a string of the same taxonomy, you can do this:

```
<?php
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url( $wp->request ) . '/'; // last part adds the "/" at the end
?>
```

Then for the canonical meta (*or any other permalink placement*):

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $current_url ?>" />
```

Observe, this will fail for url:s that have query strings at the end and is only for "pretty urls", like `domain.com/category/sub-category/`.